# How can I make the logo perspective propotional?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo, perspective

Im having problems designing a simple logo. The reason is because I want to get the perspective right and I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Can someone help?

[image: Here is some corrections I got with the perspective, but it still not right]

[image: This is the logo I need to work on]

Comment: What's wrong with the sketch? It seems to highlight mostly everything that needs to be done.

Comment: I have tried to use the 2 perspective grid system, but it looks so wrong when I Illustrate it. I would like the perspective and lines width to be even and proportional. Yes, I would like someone to replicate it for me in illustrator so I can then use it and study it... this is becoming so complicated and it shouldn't be, thats why I am asking for help.

Comment: Welcome to graphicdesign.stackexchange. The lines can be proportional or even. They can't be both at the same time. A wide line becomes thinner as it recedes (proportion). An even line that does not become thinner with distance is out of proportion. The grid is most successful with illustrating shapes having right (90°) angles. Many of your shapes have angles that are not square, so they might not appear to align with the square grid you want to impose.

Comment: @Doll201789 Requests for free work are strictly off-topic here. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I dont have a lot of time, but i will leave this here. While angles and line directions are not preserved by perspective, intersections of lines are so you canb cross the corners of any rectangle to find its halfway (or indeed any division).

[image]

Comment: THANK YOU! Is this the exact grid measurement? I feel a bit slow asking this, but obviously I haven't tested it yet using it. Also what exactly do you mean with your words? 

I know this sounds lazy, but this shouldn't take so long for someone that understands the base. Do you think its possible to fix this problem so I can then study it?

Comment: @Doll201789 yes its a division by 2 if thats what you were after.

Answer (score 0):

It's obvious that you have a grasp of how to do a mechanical 2-point perspective drawing. Why not simply do that right in Illustrator? Make a new layer with your perspective guides (there's also a perspective tool) then align your logo to that?

Comment: I am using Illustrator CC. And for some reason I find it so hard to learn how to use the ¨perspective grid tool¨ I looked at many resources. What is your best advice for this matter?

Also, regarding the layers, I already done this. But the problem I have is that the 2 point perspective system is becoming SO COMPLICATED! I can't get it right. I was hoping someone was gonna fix a drawing for me in this forum, then I could analyse it to understand how it worked.

Comment: @Doll201789 i do not think that is waht was advocated but doing the perspective drawing with lines like my image comment says.

Comment: You can easily find free tutorials on how to use the perspective tool online.

Comment: Can you show me a sample? This is why I am asking for help, because I can`t figure it out with tutorials. Thanks

Comment: There already exists a huge amount of samples and examples, readily available for free via tutorial videos and images. My adding to the pile would be a waste of time. CTRL+Shift+i, then 1, 2, and 3 to select your plane. It's actually quite straight forward.

Comment: And for what it's worth, you don't even need the perspective tool. A drawing like the one you're trying to do would be easy to do 100% manually by drawing a two-point perspective using regular lines, then convert them to guides (Ctrl+5) . Essentially just do what you did on paper. There's no magic to it.